# upload apk on play store without launcher activity?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console, android-launcher

I have an app which should triggered from my parent app only. In that case I don't need launcher activity (since I am triggering that with my parent app). All I want to know that is play store allow to upload an app without launcher activity. Any lead ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google Play requires that every program have a launcher activity. The **AndroidManifest.xml** file for the application provides the launcher activity, which is recognized by the following attribute:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intet.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Therefore, you will need a launcher activity to be specified.